# remove time stamp from string

Tags: php, date

can anyone get me a code for hiding the time stamp from a string.
I used this code to get the date from the string
suppose the

```
$date_string = "02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm";

$date = strtotime($date_string);
$date = date('m/d/y', $date);
```

But the out put I am getting is something like this

```
 1/1/70
```

Please suggest a better way that I could implement for this to work
I want it to show like

```
02/06/2011
```

Comment: is date_string hidden? Why dont you share it?

Comment: It would be nice if you add what the string contains first.

Comment: and it would be useful to see how you output final $date value

Comment: If you're getting 1/1/1970 as you're output, then the string isn't getting converting to a valid timestamp, as 1 January 1970 is the UNIX epoch. Looking at your string, I think it's because you have a time range (`11:00 am - 2:00 pm`); a range can't be converted to a time stamp.

Comment: so what you sa is that the time '02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm' is not a convert-able standard

Comment: a date can only be 1 date, not 2, therefor you cant have a range. its called a 'date', not a 'dateRange' :-) btw: explode(' ',$date_string). index 0 gives you the date. The reason it gives you 1/1/70 is because its not a readable format which gives you 0, which is the start of the unix epoch, which is 01 01 1970 according to date functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the date you're looking for is already in the string and all you want to do is remove the time range, you don't need any date manipulation. Just remove everything after the space (assuming the format of the `date_string` remains consistent).

```
$date_string = "02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm";
$date = explode(" ",$date_string);
echo $date[0];
```

Or even simpler (but untested)

```
echo strtok($date_string," ");  //http://codepad.org/Or1mpYOp
```

[PHP.NET:strtok](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

[PHP.NET:explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: You earn a line with : `echo $date[0];` I think it's the best solution here. Of course, it depends from where the `$date_string` comes from and if he can control its format.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = strtotime($date_string);
$date = getdate($date);
$date = $date['mon'] . '/' . $date['mday'] . '/' . $date['year']
```

Comment: returns the date as '1/1/1970'

Comment: Realized this was because I used a real date string as opposed to the date range string supplied in the question

Answer (score 1):

If `02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm` is what gets displayes, you're obviously displaying `$date_string` and not `$date`, because `strtotime('02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm');` returns boolean false, which `date('m/d/y', $date)` would convert to `01/01/1970`.

Try something like this

```
$date_string = "02/06/2011 11:00 am - 2:00 pm";
$date_exploded = explode('-',$date_string);

$date = strtotime($date_exploded[0]);
$date = date('m/d/y', $date);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the fact that something is going very wrong in the date parsing, you need to be aware that using a date format of 00/00/00[00] is rather ambigious - in the US dates written like this are in the format mm/dd/yy[yy] while in the UK it is interpreted as dd/mm/yy[yy]. The strtotime function does not use the locale setting to work out which applies and always assumes the former.

If I were being asked to parse this, I'd go with using preg to extract the date part. Using a pattern:

```
/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})/
```

gives an array

```
0=> 02/06/2011
1=> 02
2=> 06
3=> 2011
```

Then use mktime to generate the unix timstamp.

Other approaches include using substr to extract a fixed length string, or exploide by space to get words.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is already is date .

$date = substr($records[$datetime, 0, 10);